# Wave Solder an Alkaline Battery on a PCB (any concerns)?

Tags: batteries, soldering, alkaline

I have a specific application that requires a board to be powered by Alkaline batteries and would like to solder direct to the PCB using wave solder vs. hand solder (need to consider a high volume manufacturing method).

The battery will NOT be an SMT to the PCB, but thru-hole leads.

The battery will be be on the top of the PCB with other components, but not resting on any of the electronics.

Please send any issues, problems, or suggestions to push this forward and minimize rework, scrap, or wounded materials. Any consideration to damaging the Alkaline battery?

Example of leads, not the actual Alkaline battery to be used.

[image]

Comment: I struggle to believe that the battery datasheet says nothing about this topic.

Comment: Is the rest of the board SMT or through-hole ?

Comment: Permanently attaching a non-rechargeable battery could be a problem.

Comment: @bitsmack: Yeah, I don't understand why you would want to solder a non-rechargeable battery either. Environmentally, it is just not friendly at all. And I think it should matter.

Comment: I actually contacted the battery supplier (Panasonic) and they provided the temp range but had no data on dwell time related to wave solder vs. temperature.  Basic data was up to 130C but that is cooler than a wave solder bath.  Key the battery supplier said was dwell time.  The product is a one time use and Li-battery can't be used in this application due to transportation needs. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you shown us a lithium because you failed to find the equivalent photo with an alkaline battery. Actually, I doubt you can find pre-made alkaline batteries with the terminals as shown. So if your concern is manufacturability, that's something to check first.

Moreover, in case your circuit is mainly SMT with only the alkaline battery being through hole, I think it is worth it to ask the factory which solution is more expensive: reflow+manual soldering of the alkaline, or wave soldering with SMT+TH. I'm not sure the second is the cheapest.

Actually, I think the chapest and safest way to address this problem is to

- choose standard SMT contacts for the batteries (e.g. Keystone makes some)
- manufacture the whole board including contacts with standard pick-n-place + reflow process (without the battery of course)
- have, during the assembly (I guess there is an enclosure anyway), a step to insert standard AA battery

Moreover, if you need to change the battery at some point, it's a lot easier.

Comment: Thank you for the comments...I think it is going to come down to an experiment (DOE) through the wave solder a view the characteristics of the solder joint.  I was also considering to shorten the dwell time, have a larger pad on the back where the pins come through the PCB (thru-hole) and have connectivity electrically to this pad vs. expecting some thru-hold wicking into the thru-hole.  We have a high volume requirement, has to be cheap solution.